# svn tag similar with HEAD^ of git

Tags: svn

First sorry about my poor English.

I used to use  at git. 
"git diff -rHEAD:HEAD^

But svn doesn't have HEAD^

How can I indicate the previous of HEAD revision number easily?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is a Two-Step Process

It looks like SVN doesn't support that type of syntax.  The manual and other posts online seem to support this (see below).

Derived from http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-10/0356.shtml:

```
#!/bin/bash
REPO=http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn
HEAD=`svn info $REPO | sed -E -n 's%^Revision: %%p'`
svn diff -c-$HEAD $REPO
```

### Sources

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords
- http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2007-10/0296.shtml